# What is .. operator in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget customWidget(int position){
    return Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(position),
    child: Container(
      color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.lightBlueAccent: Colors.black87,
    ),
  )
}
```

What is **..** in **Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(position)** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does that 2 dots mean? What is the difference between 1 and 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136945/what-does-that-2-dots-mean-what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-2)

Answer (score 3):

[Cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-)

From  the official documentation

> Cascades (..) allow you to make a sequence of operations on the same
>   object.
>
> In addition to function calls, you can also access fields on that
>   same object. This often saves you the step of creating a temporary
>   variable and allows you to write more fluid code.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation) ,

> Cascades (..) allow you to make a sequence of operations on the same object. In addition to function calls, you can also access fields on that same object. This often saves you the step of creating a temporary variable and allows you to write more fluid code.
>
> Consider the following code:

```
querySelector('#confirm') // Get an object.
  ..text = 'Confirm' // Use its members.
  ..classes.add('important')
  ..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

> The first method call, querySelector(), returns a selector object. The
>   code that follows the cascade notation operates on this selector
>   object, ignoring any subsequent values that might be returned.
>
> The previous example is equivalent to:

```
var button = querySelector('#confirm');
button.text = 'Confirm';
button.classes.add('important');
button.onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'))
```