# Not able to call `toString()` on StringBuffer when using cascading notation

Tags: dart

Say, I have:

```
var buffer = StringBuffer();
buffer.toString(); // works (understandable)

buffer.write('foo').toString(); // fails because `write` returns `void` (understandable)

buffer..write('bar').toString(); // but why does it fail?
```

You can see `buffer..write('bar')` returns a `StringBuffer` instance, and I should be able to call `toString()` on that instance. But why it doesn't work that way.

---

PS: I know I can use `buffer..write('bar')..toString()` to make it work but my question is not how to make that work rather I want to know the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is how the cascade operator is suppose to work.

```
buffer..write('bar').toString();
```

Is equal to do:

```
buffer.write('bar').toString();
```

Where:

```
buffer..write('bar')..toString();
```

Is equal to:

```
buffer.write('bar');
buffer.toString();
```

What you can do to make your example works is to add bracket like this so we changes the order of how each part is linked:

```
(buffer..write('bar')).toString();
```

Also found this answer which also gives some details about this behavior:
[How do method cascades work exactly in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025769/how-do-method-cascades-work-exactly-in-dart)